# Foundation scss not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, zurb-foundation

So I set up a new project in Angular with foundation scss,

In my angular.json i have this.

```
"styles": [
          "src/styles.scss
        ],
```

and in my styles.scss I have this

```
/* You can add global styles to this file, and also import other style files*/
@import '@foundation-sites/scss/foundation';
```

My template doesnt show any foundation changes when I load it. and also it gives me and error saying the globals variables I am using are not found, But when I import this same line in a child component where I am using the global variables , It doesnt complain but and the global variables, I am guessing are passed as the error goes away but then the template is not affected by foundation and looks very ugly , help.

Comment: looking forward to an answer on this one as well...
I'm following this steps [https://shermandigital.com/blog/zurb-foundation-with-angular-cli/], got all paths remapped and the console does not show any errors but Angular's initial HTML remains the same and looks unstyled.

Answer (score 0):

In the src/assets/directory, create a directory named foundation-siteswith empty files named: _settings.scssand _global.scss.

In the _global.scssfile, paste the content from: node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/_global.scss.

In the _settings.scssfile, paste the content from: node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/settings/_settings.scss.

In the _settings.scssfile, find the line with @import 'util/util';and change it to point to the proper directory:
@import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';

In src/styles.sass, add the import statements from node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/foundation.scss, adjusting the directory path as in the example below. Note that we are using our custom settings and global files that we placed in the src/assets/foundation-sitesdirectory.

```
  /**
     * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
     * Version 6.3.0
     * foundation.zurb.com
     * Licensed under MIT Open Source
     */

    // Dependencies
    @import "../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/normalize-scss/sass/normalize";
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/helpers/missing-dependencies';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/helpers/true';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/purge';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/remove';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/replace';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/_vendor/sassy-lists/stylesheets/functions/to-list';

    // Sass utilities
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/util/util';

    // Settings (Custom)
    @import "assets/foundation-sites/settings";

    // Global variables and styles (Custom)
    @import 'assets/foundation-sites/global';

    // Components
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/grid/grid';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/typography/typography';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/forms/forms';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/visibility';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/float';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/button';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/button-group';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion-menu';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/accordion';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/badge';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/breadcrumbs';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/callout';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/card';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/close-button';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/drilldown';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/dropdown-menu';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/dropdown';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/flex';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/responsive-embed';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/label';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/media-object';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/menu';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/menu-icon';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/off-canvas';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/orbit';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/pagination';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/progress-bar';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/reveal';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/slider';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/sticky';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/switch';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/table';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/tabs';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/title-bar';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/top-bar';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/thumbnail';
    @import '../node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/components/tooltip';

    @mixin foundation-everything($flex: false) {
      @if $flex {
        $global-flexbox: true !global;
      }

      @include foundation-global-styles;
      @if not $flex {
        @include foundation-grid;
      }
      @else {
        @include foundation-flex-grid;
      }
      @include foundation-typography;
      @include foundation-forms;
      @include foundation-button;
      @include foundation-accordion;
      @include foundation-accordion-menu;
      @include foundation-badge;
      @include foundation-breadcrumbs;
      @include foundation-button-group;
      @include foundation-callout;
      @include foundation-card;
      @include foundation-close-button;
      @include foundation-menu;
      @include foundation-menu-icon;
      @include foundation-drilldown-menu;
      @include foundation-dropdown;
      @include foundation-dropdown-menu;
      @include foundation-responsive-embed;
      @include foundation-label;
      @include foundation-media-object;
      @include foundation-off-canvas;
      @include foundation-orbit;
      @include foundation-pagination;
      @include foundation-progress-bar;
      @include foundation-slider;
      @include foundation-sticky;
      @include foundation-reveal;
      @include foundation-switch;
      @include foundation-table;
      @include foundation-tabs;
      @include foundation-thumbnail;
      @include foundation-title-bar;
      @include foundation-tooltip;
      @include foundation-top-bar;
      @include foundation-visibility-classes;
      @include foundation-float-classes;

      @if $flex {
        @include foundation-flex-classes;
      }
    }

    @include foundation-everything(true);
```

Rename the /src/styles.sassfile to have the SCSS file extension: /src/styles.scss.

Open angular-cli.json in the root directory of the app and, under apps.styles, change "styles.sass"to "styles.scss".

In angular-cli.json(if angular <6) or angular.json (if angular 6+)
 change defaults.styleExtfrom "sass"to "scss".